# Переменная в запросе к API

Tags: javascript, vue.js

В зависимости от введенного значения пользователем - может измениться запрос, который нужно выполнить.

Вопрос в том как правильно передать эти данные в запрос к API?

Проект на VUE

```js
export default{
  name: 'Second',
  data(){
    return{
      posts: [],
      name: ''
 
    }
  },
 methods:{
  limits: async function(){
  let res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_limit=',limit);
    const posts = await res.json();
    this.posts = posts

  },
  getName: function(){
    this.limit = this.name
    
  }
 }
}
```

```css
.post{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: 25%;

}
```

```html
<div id="app">

<button v-on:click="limits">Кнопка</button>

<input v-model="name" @input="getName">



  <div class="post" v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
  <h2>{{post.title}}</h2>
  <p>{{post.body}}</p>
  </div>




</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

просто передайте в качестве параметра запроса объект в JS это будет выглядеть так:
{param1:value,param2:value}

```
 let res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?',{param1:value,param2:value});
```

Имя передаваемого параметра и значение попадут в запрос